# In two <input> fields in one form, how to set first <input> value fix and reset second <input> value after refresh page

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript code i have 4 input fields and one submit button. When click on SUBMIT button the first input field value should be fix not to change and remaining 3 input fields should reset to empty fields after filling some data.

And I am calling page refresh function in SUBMIT button.

So whenever i am clicking to submit button my first input also getting refresh.

Could any one please look into that and help fix this issue.

Thanks in advance....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function refreshPage(){
window.location.reload();
}
</script>
<script>
function incrementValue(){
var value = " " + parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('number').value = "00" + value;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
First Input Value should set after refresh page : <input type="text" 
id="number" value="001" readonly/><br>
Second Input Value should reset : <input type="text" autofocus /><br>
Third Input Value should reset: <input type="text" autofocus /><br>
Forth Input Value should reset : <input type="text" autofocus /><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="incrementValue(), refreshPage()" 
>Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `localStorage`, which allows you to get information from webpage even after refreshing it.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Thanks for your support 

From this link i am not getting any thing which is related to my question

Comment: When you submit form, you should put first input value to localStorage. Using localStorage.setItem() then when page reloaded you should get value from local storage and put value to input text filed using localStorage.getItem() ... You just need  to get Item in OnLoad () event of document.